# How to create a Dev/Test environment on Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, database-administration, test-environments

On the Holy Book of SQL Server [The Messiah once described](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/dev-test-and-production-sql-server-environments/) how a Test/Dev environment should look like in a perfect World:

*"In a perfect world, my test/QA servers get restored nightly from production. Let’s say every night at 9pm, the production full backups kick off, and they’re finished by 10pm. At 11pm, the QA box kicks off a restore job that grabs the latest full backups off the file share and restores them."*

This makes sense in an on-prem scenario but what if I have to migrate to Azure SQL Database?

Because if I really want to test the Test/Dev environment need to be on Azure SQL Database too!

The questions are:

1. Should I create a logic that restore a backup from Production every night?
2. Does delete/restore database on Azure has a cost? (I mean if I do it 30 times per month?)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sure.  No different from on prem.
2. Dev/Test can be on a lower SLO, perhaps Serverless.  There is no other cost to restore a database.